# Adding sum of rows in a particular column and store in the same dataframe pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

eg:
df

```
|Exchange Rate Type|From-currency|To-currency|
+------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|               456|          456|        456|   
                456|          456         456|
+------------------+-------------+-----------+
```

result df:

```
---------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|col1              |col2         |col3        |**sum**
+------------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|               456|          456|        456|   sum
                456|          456         456|sum
+------------------+-------------+-----------+
               912           912       912     sum
```

in **pyspark?**

Comment: How will you identify which is a sum row and which is a regular row. ?

Comment: do you just want a column total on both axis?

Comment: @Manakin Column sum appended as the last row to the dataframe

Comment: @RahulKumar Sum will be the last row in the dataframe